# question about $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0$ if and only if $\|f_n\|_p\to\|f\|_p$

Tags: real-analysis

Assumption: $f_n\to f$ pointwise a.e., and $f_n$ and $f$ are $L^p$ functions.

My question is whether it is necessary to check the case $p=\infty$. If so, why and how to write it down rigorously? Thanks!

Comment: This is a problem in my book. I think the assumption $1\leq p<\infty$ should be added.

Comment: Mathematicians in general and authors in particular are famous for leaving out hypotheses.

Answer (score 2):

The $\infty$ norm behaves much differently than the finite $p$ norms. Consider $f,f_n$ defined on $\mathbf R$ as follows: $f(x) = 1$ and $f_n(x) = \chi_{[-n,n]}(x)$. Then $\|f\|_\infty = 1$, $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$, and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ everywhere. But $\|f_n - f\|_\infty = 1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the direct implication is always true by triangle inequality.

The converse is false for $p=\infty$ which can be proved with a counterexample. Take for example $f_n(x)=x^n$ in $[0,1]$ and $f_n(x)=1$ on $[1,2]$.

I suspect this question is a duplicate ...